# SwiftUI Xcode 12.5 with very basic NavigationView layout Issues

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, xcode12.5

I have been developing iOS for about a decade and every time I try to take the dive into SwiftUI I spend more time than ever wrestling what should seemingly be a simple task. While working on an app with very simple navigation setup I kept seeing two errors in the console: `Unable to present. Please file a bug.` and `Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <_TtGC7SwiftUI19UIHostingControllerGVS_15ModifiedContentVVS_22_VariadicView_Children7ElementGVS_18StyleContextWriterVS_19SidebarStyleContext___: 0x7fd913d0bd90>`. The first happens when there are at least **3 Views**  to navigate from (I don't understand why this is a significant threshold and my end goal uses a `LazyVGrid` with a `ForEach`) with navigation links and the second error happens on rotating to landscape and then back to portrait. I believed this to be related to how the phone is presenting the sidebar but even changing to `StackNavigationViewStyle` produced similar problems.

If this were a UIKit application I can absolutely solve for the Unbalanced calls situation but SwiftUI really takes away some of the lower level capabilities that I am used to having control of when it comes to building Views and navigation stacks.

I finally attempted to just start a new project from scratch and place the minimal amount of code in the ContentView:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Number 1")) {
                    Text("Number 1")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Number 2")) {
                    Text("Number 2")
                }
                NavigationLink(destination: Text("Number 3")) {
                    Text("Number 3")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Running the above code produced the issues on rotation. Another issue that I came across was when you press the `< back` button after these issues start, the navigation stops working completely and the "detail" view never gets updated.

It is clear that the direction is SwiftUI so I am trying to really go this direction (maybe next week will have some amazing improvements) but this seems to be a pretty significant issue on a very simple set of code. I am hoping that I am just doing something wrong that someone can point out quickly.

**EDITED:**

After more exploration I found that the second error happens on the 11, 11 Pro Max, and 12 Pro Max where the navigation stack changes to the sidebar by default. Changing the style to `StackNavigationViewStyle` does eliminate the second error (but doesn't help if I do want to use the sidebar style) but the first error remains. To Schottky's point, changing `VStack` to `List` will also eliminate the first error. However a newer convention (based on WWDC videos at least) to solve for collection views I believe is to use a `LazyV/HGrid` with a `ForEach` within it which is actually what I am attempting to accomplish. I didn't put that as my code here since I wanted the be able to reproduce the error in the simplest form of course to ensure it wasn't something buried in my view hierarchy.

Comment: A lot of times you will - unfortunately - find that if you do things in a way that Apple does not 'intent' it to do, it won't work resp. doesn't work too well. We can only hope that they fix that in the future. Usually, a `NavigationView` displays a `List`. Now if you replace the `VStack` with a `List`, all works well. It's a little bit of an unsatisfactory answer but I'm afraid that this is the only valid answer at the moment.

Comment: I do understand that point and that apple pushing that direction so I tried this of course and found that the first error went away but the unbalanced calls remained leading me to believe that this may be a bug in the framework. If this truly is the direction that apple is pushing then it doesn't make much sense as I would have to have every NavigationView start with a List. What if I wanted 3 buttons instead? I would still get this same issue. Seems to me this is too much a restriction that they may still be working out. Maybe next week will show some improvement.

Comment: I'm not saying that Apple is requiring you to do things their way but I have found numerous times that when you don't do it 'their' way it gets tedious, and/or error-prone. I just suspect they might test code better when it is what they need. But I couldn't replicate your second error with the code you gave, is there anything more to it?

Comment: There isn't more to it but what I am finding is VERY interesting: the second error only happens on 11/11 Pro Max, and 12 Pro Max. 11 vs 12 handles the navigation differently where the 11 follows the pattern of the Max series with the Master->Detail format (sidebar). I am still pushing forward with SwiftUI but this doesn't seem to be a case where I am doing anything wrong. Of course if there is a better way to handle a single column collection view with SwiftUI (without changing global tableview appearance) then I am all ears! I remove that from above to simplify the issue but that is the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I was able to accomplish this was via a post I found at HackingWithSwift [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/forums/swiftui/unable-to-present-please-file-a-bug/7901/8237). I still had to use `.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())` to eliminate a different error as it seems that the initial iterations of SwiftUI focuses on the 80% of cases where multiple NavigationLinks only really exist in the `List` View type. I have not tested this with the latest beta but if you try to use the other navigation style (Column) it will throw another error: `unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transactions`. I am okay with this for now as this at least allows me to create a screen that does not have line separators and navigation arrows....I just don't have the Master-Detail setup by default.